# SciPy's lsim not behaving as expected compared to Python Control Systems Library

Tags: python, scipy

I am doing some control engineering in Python, and I have come accross a very strange discrepency between [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html) and the [Python Control Systems Library](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.matlab.lsim.html) for the implementation of the `lsim` command. To the best of my knowledge, these commands should behave identically, but it seems they are not: more particularly, the output of the SciPy command seems like nonsense. I have included a MWE below.

```
"""
Minimal working example (MWE) replicating the discrepency between lsim for the SciPy module and control module
"""

# Import modules
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sgnl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control as ctrl
import control.matlab as ctrl_mtl

# Number of samples
N_k = 100    # Total number of outputs

# Continous-time (unstable) open loop system dynamics
A = np.array([[0, 1],
              [-2, 3]])
B = np.array([[0],
              [1]])
n_x = A.shape[0]
n_u = B.shape[1]

# Initial state
x_0 = np.array([[1], [1]], dtype=float)

# Sampling period
h = 0.5

# Controller (full-state feedback)
K = np.array([[0, -4]])

# Closed-loop (stable) continous-time system
sys_cl_scipy = sgnl.StateSpace(A + B @ K, np.zeros((n_x, 1)), np.eye(n_x), np.zeros((n_x, 1)))
sys_cl_ctrl = ctrl.StateSpace(A + B @ K, np.zeros((n_x, 1)), np.eye(n_x), np.zeros((n_x, 1)))

# Simulate dynamics
# NOTE: The only difference is that for SciPy to work I need to add np.ravel(), as otherwise I get the error
# "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2,)"
_, _, x_scipy = sgnl.lsim(sys_cl_scipy, None, np.linspace(0, h * (N_k - 1), N_k), X0=np.ravel(x_0), interp=False)
_, _, x_ctrl = ctrl_mtl.lsim(sys_cl_ctrl, T=np.linspace(0, h * (N_k - 1), N_k), X0=x_0)
x_scipy = x_scipy.T
x_ctrl = x_ctrl.T

# Plot the state through state-space (verification)
fig_verify, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.ravel(x_scipy[0, :]), np.ravel(x_scipy[1, :]), label="x SciPy", color="green")
ax.plot(np.ravel(x_ctrl[0, :]), np.ravel(x_ctrl[1, :]), label="x control", color="blue")
plt.legend()
plt.title("State trajectory")

# Display all plots
plt.show()
```

This gives this as result.

[image: plot with a spiraly ctrl phase trajectory and an L shaped bogus scipy one]

The control implementation works as expected, but the SciPy implementation seems completely wrong. Is there something I am missing, or how should I interpret this? Thanks in advance.

I tried to compare both methods on an identical setup, and they produce different results, whilst they both should simulate the output of a continous-time LTI system.

Comment: I can't help, but it's a pleasure to see a well-asked question. Welcome :)

Comment: The order of the outputs is different between the `scipy` implimentation & the `control` impleimentation, **Scipy**: time, response, evolution. **Control**: response, time, evolution. Basically you're ploting the wrong return values from `scipy`'s lsim.

Comment: @DrBwts the code only uses the third return value, which should be the same in both cased based on your comment.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Yes, thank you :) I am aware the first two arguments differ in their order, but as you state the third output should be identical.

Comment: Works with [_, _, x_scipy = sgnl.lsim2(sys_cl_scipy, None, np.linspace(0, h * (N_k - 1), N_k), X0=np.ravel(x_0))](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim2.html)

Comment: You should probably report this to [Scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues) as `lsim2` is going to get canned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be running into a typing problem (as in the numerical type of the variables, not hitting keys with your fingers ). Your array `A` is an array of integers, and `lsim` uses the data type of `A` to determine the data type of the output array.  You can fix this by ensuring that the data type of `A` is floating point:

```
A = np.array([[0.0, 1.0],
              [-2.0, 3.0]])
```

P.S. I'm pretty sure anyone running `lsim`--which simulates a continuous-time system--would expect the calculation to use floating point values, so I'd call this a bug.  I created an issue for this in the SciPy github repo: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18982

Comment: Many thanks! This indeed seems to be the problem, I should have noticed in hindsight that the values returned by SciPy are all integers . And I fully agree that this should be reported as a bug (or, at the least, explicitly mentioned) as you'll come across integer LTI dynamics often, and I can't think of a single use why you would want the evolution of the states to be integers as well :)